# Why am I getting ValueError when I try to merge two Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two pandas data frames. Below is the head info of the data frames.

```
hosts.head()
    Edition     NOC
0   1896    GRE
1   1900    FRA
2   1904    USA
3   1908    GBR
4   1912    SWE

reshaped.head()
    Edition     NOC     Change
0   1896    AFG     NaN
1   1900    AFG     NaN
2   1904    AFG     NaN
3   1908    AFG     NaN
4   1912    AFG     NaN
```

Below is the error message. Please suggest what is wrong here and how to correct it. Thanks.

```
merged = pd.merge(reshaped, hosts)
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-b8f539a538e3> in <module>
      1 # Merge reshaped and hosts: merged
----> 2 merged = pd.merge(reshaped, hosts)
........................................
........................................
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns.
```

Comment: check `dtypes` for both the dataframes and you will be able to figure out. the error message seems pretty clear

Comment: Thank you very much. Converted the column in reshaped dataframe to int type. It works.